# ValueError: invalid literal

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, arraylist

```
def _init_(self. row, col, data):
    self.child = {}
    self.row = row
    self.col = col
    self.data = data
    self.active = True

file = open('filename.txt', 'r')
maze = file.readlines()
n = (intmaze[0])
full = maze[1:(n*n)+1]
file.close
```

***Value error: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'2,1,1,3\n'***

I am trying to read a text file with the following matrix

2,1,1,3

2,1,2,3

1,1,2,3

3,G,3,1

Comment: You have to split the lines on commas and pass each individual value to `int()`. Also you have the `G` value. It won't work on `int()`.

Comment: With the `maze[0]` you are accessing the first line. WHich specifically is `'2,1,1,3\n'`. The `int()` typecasting doesn't know how to process this literal, because of the `\n` and commas.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: from your code your file should probably more resembe this string: `"4\n2,1,1,3\n2,1,2,3\n1,1,2,3\n3,G,3,1"` with the first line ONLY containing one number which specifies the dimensions of the following matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have replace `n = int(maze[0])` with the following -> 
You have to first store it into list by `l = maze.split(",")` then you can write `n = len(l)` to get the length of the matrix.

Comment: `maze` is a list of strings. you cannot use `split` on a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("maze.txt","r") as fd:
    maze = [i.split(",") for i in fd.read().splitlines()]
print(len(maze[0]))
print(maze)
```